# Is texting required for Apple Watch fall detection?

Tags: apple-watch

The Apple Watch Series 4 and above fall detection function transmits your location after a fall.  Is this information sent as a text?  If I have a talk-only phone plan without texting, for example, would the location still be transmitted as part of the emergency call?

Comment: Thank you.  Consumer Cellular has a $20 plan with talk only.  However the $15 T-Mobile Connect plan includes text.  (Just shopping for the simplest plan for my mother in law.)

Answer (score 3):

None of this data is sent as an iMessage or SMS.

> If I have a talk-only phone plan without texting, for example, would the location still be transmitted as part of the emergency call?

If you have a **talk only** plan with no texting (do those still exist?), it won't be able to send GPS location data at all.  How would it? "Talk Only" means just that - talk - there's no data whatsoever so it couldn't send location data.  It's a moot point anyway.

The way fall detection works is that after a fall has been detected and you haven't responded, it makes a voice call to the programmed emergency number and plays an audio message that includes latitude and longitudinal data.

From Apple Support [Use fall detection with Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208944)

> When the call connects, your Apple Watch plays an audio message that informs emergency services that your Apple Watch detected a hard fall and then it shares your current location as latitude and longitude coordinates.

So, to answer your question, yes, the location would be transmitted, **as audio** as part of the emergency call.